# how to know device IP is static or dhcp on linux dhcp server

Tags: linux, dhcp, static-ip

My system is Linux. I use udhcpd tool to build a dhcp server.
I want to know what method(static or dhcp) is used for connected device on my linux server
How can I do? do have any cmd can reach this goal?

Thank you!!

Comment: If it's in your lease list, its used DHCP. If not -then it's Static… But this is a Basic Business Admin knowledge…?! And if you set up a forced IP, with a MAC, and it's reachable by this. It worked as expected. I don't see really here a business relationship or environmental question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ip` tool. This tells your whether the IP is `dynamic` or not.
Below is an example output which shows the keyword `dynamic`. This means there was some dynamic process (e.g. DHCP) to fetch the IP.

```
$ ip address
...
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.184/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 65779sec preferred_lft 65779sec
```

In addition you can list all your interfaces/IPs which have `dynamic` (or `permanent`) IP addresses with e.g. `ip address show dynamic`. See also https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/iproute2/ip-address.8.en.html